# Custom filter and search - "Use no more than 240 characters" warning

Tags: bug, custom-filter

I tried to modify search to remove some tags after applying my custom filter. Turns out I cannot have more than 240 characters there!

[image]

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create filter with lots of tags;
2. Apply filter - search bar will
   be also updated;
3. Modify value in search bar and try to apply
   changes.

Excepted behavior: new search is done based on updated value from search bar.

Comment: I've a filter with even more tags than yours and I can't edit the search line (well, I can delete but not add any characters). Yet, I don't even get the error message.